# What to do for eye/retina "burn-in" now that we're all darkened up?

Tags: interface-design, user-experience, best-practice

Like many, I've been so excited since I switched to dark mode on macOS. I've been able to work at night and in my studio with dim lighting so much easier. My eyes feel so much better now! But this has come at a price...

I'm now frequently finding myself having "lines" and shapes in my vision when I look away from my monitor. It's really very similar to CRT or even LCD burn-in from what I can tell. The longer I stare at a design or document, the worse it is and when I simply blink I see the afterimage still pretty darn acutely.

Are there any suggestions or aids for preventing or minimizing this both for ourselves personally and in our designs for users of systems we design?

Comment: I think the real answer is to start working ONLY 8 hours during normal office hours.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really graphic design related. It may be more suited for https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/ as this is more a "how the human body works" type of question. It's really not any different than moving from a bright environment for an extended period to a sudden dark setting - it takes time for the cones and rods in the eyes to adjust. Minimizing exposure time, or making the transition between dark and light more slowly are really the only solutions I'm aware of.

Comment: Switch the lights on. Don't work in the dark. You're just fooling yourself into thinking it's 'better'.

Comment: Honestly guys, I think you're really wrong here about the lights on stuff vs dark work. I figured out the solution after really thinking hard about this after seeing your comments. The real solution I'm finding is reducing contrast while maintaining a dark env. Sepia levels can help to reduce the blue a bit (which seems to help), but yeah, I'm finding my eyes are in much better shape just after an hour of really going through and reducing contrast where possible. I think Apple and Microsoft will probably understand this soon and implement this themselves to help users to have less "burn-in".

Comment: .. unless.. as a designer.. you want to actually have *accurate* color representation on screen `:)` There are apps such as Flux which are designed to eliminate some blue-cast as the time of day changes. But.. they alter color... which is *horrible* in a design environment.  30+ years with black type on a  white screen and I have no complaints. Dark mode is a fad.. a trend... a mistake for a designer. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: I agree with @Scott, black interface is a trend and I too think it looks cool, but the contrast to simulated white paper is straining for the eyes. If you have to work at night you should also be in a well-lit room. Yes, it will keep you awake, but you can't half-sleep while working anyway so you might as well go all in. Furthermore I remember my color management teacher talking about how too much contrast affects a monitor's ability to display colors accurately. He advised me to always have a neutral gray background as the the best compromise for both dark and light images.